# Can't migrate my website from localhost to webhost

Tags: migrations

I can easily install Drupal 7.37 on my webhosting. But cannot migrate the existing website. 
I uploaded all the files. Imported the database. Changed settings.php accordingly. But what I see is only 404 - http://www.hostinger.com.ua/oshibka_404.
The basic link is www.orger.besaba.com. What do I do wrong?